Creating a 'circle' around adjacent objects in a circle
I'm writing solutions to a permuations problems and have one question relating to adjacent objects positioned in a circle.
I have created the following code to draw 6 points on a circle.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={node distance=2ex}]
            \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
            \node (\i) at (60*\i:2.1) {\textbullet};
            \node[right of=3] {$p_1$};
            \node[right of=2] {$p_2$};
            \node[right of=1] {};
            \node[right of=5] {};
            \node[right of=4] {};
            \node[right of=6] {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}

Which looks like this:

I would like to enclose the 2 points $p_1$, and $p_2$ to indicate these points are to be treated as one unit, like the image below.

Any help appreciated.  I'm quite willing to change the entire code to satisfy my requirement.

The fit library is designed for this purpose. The command
\node[draw, fit=(a)(b)(c), <additional options>]{<content of new node>};

will draw a node around the given named points. I included the shape ellipse, which requires the shapes.geometric library.
Unrelated: I renamed your nodes p1 etc., and changed their coordinates so their names match their labels. Also, instead of creating a new node for each label, you can label each node as in the code below. The syntax is label=<angle>:<content>. And instead of putting a text bullet in each node, you can fill them, which gives you more control over their size, color, etc. I created a style dot so you could easily reuse it in another tikzpicture.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, shapes.geometric}

\tikzset{dot/.style={circle, draw, fill, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=3.5pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={node distance=2ex}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,6}
            \node[dot, label=0:$p_\i$] (p\i) at (240-60*\i:2.1){};
        \node[draw=red, ellipse, fit=(p1)(p2), rotate fit=-30, yscale=1.2, thick]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
    
\end{document}


WOW Sandy.  Thank-you so much.  That is just what I'm looking for.

Any chance of explaining what you have done?

@Stephan Refer to https://tikz.dev/library-fit#autosec-5767 with explanations of fit

Brilliant!  Thanks @Jasper.
